# "shell escape" is not enabled - chemscheme/chemstyle

Tags: pdftex, eps, shell-escape, chemstyle

I am having issues with `-shell-escape`. I do not know really what this is, and how to apply it. Furthermore, I have read elsewhere that I is possibly dangerous to summon this command. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

In order to incorporate a simplified numbering system for compounds in my document, I am trying to replace a TMP marker within a `chemdraw` `.eps` file. However, when I include

```
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

I get this message:

[image]

If I remove the above command then the typset completes, but the TMP markers in the graphic remain TMP1, TMP2 etc.

This is my input:

```
\begin{scheme}[ht]
\schemeref[TMP1]{\CNlabel{MT004}}
\schemeref[TMP2]{\CNlabel{MT002}}
\schemeref[TMP3]{\CNlabel{MT005}}
\schemeref[TMP4]{\CNlabel{MT006}}
\schemeref[TMP5]{\CNlabel{MT007}}
\schemeref[TMP6]{\CNlabel{MT009}}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{RS001.eps}
\caption{Macrocycle synthesis}
\end{scheme}
```

The tutorial I am following is detailed here: http://www.jkwchui.com/2010/03/writing-chemistry-with-latex-33/

I am using TeXShop for Mac.

Comment: on the command line it means literally adding the option `--shell-escape` It is probably a configuration option in texshop but I can not help with that. It is needed to allow tex to call out to the operating system to (for example) convert eps to pdf. as any command that can call to the operating system it could in theory be misused to run commands that you don't want running, but the standard auto-pst package does nothing bad:-)

Comment: I am sorry, where in the command line do you mean?

Comment: If you are running latex "by hand" you would do `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex` instead of `pdflatex myfile.tex` You just need to tell texshop to do that...

Comment: @Alastair see [Command-line interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)

Comment: You might be best running in 'traditional' `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` mode if you are having trouble: the 'magic' that replaces `TMPX` with a number can only be done with `.eps` files.

Answer (score 14):

To enable `shell escape` in TeXShop:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add it as an argument to `pdflatex`:

`$ pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex`

Always useful to check the manual:

`$ man pdflatex`