# phasor diagram incomplete (now plotting waves)

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac

I need to make some phasor diagrams. I have copy the example from 
here
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/phasor-diagram/

but in my OSX Im not getting the waves shape (see attached).

What am I missing?

Regards[image]

Comment: We don't have a crystal ball. Did you correctly copied the code given in the referenced link? Does the code compile without errors? Are your Latex packages up to date?

Comment: That code uses `gnuplot`, so you have to compile with `shell-escape` enabled, e.g. `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`. (See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111031/586 if you're using TeXshop.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please add some details! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, if you are using LaTeX then it should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Are the close voters all come from StackOverflow?

Comment: Works out-of-the box here. I suspect that `-shell-escape` (or `gnuplot` not in path) can be the problem here.